# How to centralize the load testing setup for multiple virtual/physical machines

Tags: docker, kubernetes, jmeter, load-testing

I have a highly scalable web service that is deployed to kubernetes. I want to heavily load test it with thousands of threads.

I was using **jmeter, Taurus, jmeter-maven-plugin** for load testing my service. I also tried using distributed testing with Jmeter, but the configuration is painful, no static Ip address.

I am looking for ideas to make the setup of load testing environment easy and can centralize the setup process.